# F# add a string to an array of strings

Tags: arrays, f#

I have a string in F#:

```
 let name = "Someone"
```

I also have an array of strings:

```
 let mutable arraysOfNames : string[] = [||]
```

I want to add the string name to the array arrayOfNames. How do I do that? It doesn't have to be an array, it can be a Sequence or any other collection that I can check then if it is empty or not.

Comment: Why not use a list to build up the collection and then create an array at the end when you need it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to add an item to a zero-length array. All you can do is create a new array that holds the item. The currently accepted answer, using Array.append, does not modify the input arrays; rather, it creates a new array that contains the elements of both input arrays. If you repeatedly call append to add a single element to an array, you will be using memory extremely inefficiently.

Instead, in f#, it makes much more sense to use F#'s list type, or, for some applications, ResizeArray<'T> (which is f#'s name for the standard .NET List).  If you actually need the items in an array (for example, because you have to pass them to a method whose parameter is an array type), then do as Steve suggests in his comment.  Once you have built up the collection, call `List.toArray` or `Array.ofList` if you're using an F# list, or call the `ToArray()` instance method if you're using a ResizeArray.

Example 1:

```
let mutable listOfNames : string list = []
listOfNames <- "Alice" :: listOfNames
listOfNames <- "Bob" :: listOfNames
//...
let names = listOfNames |> List.toArray
```

Example 2:

```
let resizeArrayOfNames = ResizeArray<string>()
resizeArrayOfNames.Add "Alice"
resizeArrayOfNames.Add "Bob"
let names = resizeArrayOfNames.ToArray()
```

Note that in the first example, you'll get the names in reverse order; if you need them in the same order in which they were added, you'd need

```
let names = listOfNames |> List.rev |> List.toArray
```

Answer (score 3):

For any `Seq` which is `IEnumerable<T>` alias in F# you can write this function:

```
let addToSequence aseq elm =  Seq.append aseq <| Seq.singleton elm
```

And use it this way:

```
let withSomeone = addToSequence [||] "Someone"
```

You can use `Seq.toArray` or `Seq.toList` after you get a result sequence

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Array.append](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370256.aspx).

> // Signature: Array.append : 'T [] -> 'T [] -> 'T []
>
> // Usage: Array.append array1 array2

So in your case, you can use it like this:

```
let name = "someone"
let mutable arrayOfNames = Array.append [|"test"; "abc"|] [|name|]
printfn "%A" arrayOfNames
//[|"test"; "abc"; "someone"|]
```

So you simply need to transform your string into an array (by using [|string|]). Since `Array` contains the `append` function, you can append a string this way to an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.append` with `mutable` arrays:

```
let mutable my_array = [||]
for i in 0 .. array_size do
    my_array  <- [|i|] |> Array.append my_array 
    // my_array  <- Array.append my_array [|i|]
printfn "my array is: %A" my_array
```